# Двунаправленная трассировка путей (bidirectional path tracing)

Tags: алгоритм, графика, raytracing, pathtracing

Пытаюсь постичь трассировку путей (path tracing). Пока-что разобрался лишь с самой основой - когда из каждой точки пересечения запускается луч в случайном направлении в пределах полусферы, затем снова, и так рекурсивно, пока луч не ударится в источник света. В результате такой подход приводит к тому что в случае с маленькими источниками освещения изображения получается крайне шумным.

Следующие изображения демонстрируют уровень шума в зависимости от кол-ва семплов (лучей) на пиксель.

[image: path tracing с разным кол-вом семплов на пиксель]

*Кстати, что касается лучей на пиксель - тут я тоже не уверен что все делаю правильно, ибо метод "Монте-Карло", насколько я понимаю, подразумевает что из **каждой точки пересечения** запускаются несколько лучей, а затем их результат суммируется и усредняется. Но такой подход приводит к тому, что кол-во лучей растет в геометрической прогрессии, и уже после 6 отскоков достигает неадекватных значений, поэтому я решил что лучше просто запускать изначально несколько лучей на один пиксель (чуть отклоненных от центра пикселя в случайном направлении, не выходящих за пределы пикселях), но в каждом пересечении при этом генерируется только 1 луч. Я не знаю соответствует ли данный подход "Монте-Карло" или нет, но по крайней мере так хотя бы рендеринг длится не вечно..*

**Bidirectional path tracing**

Я стал искать способы, как можно было бы уменьшить кол-во шума, и наткнулся на двунаправленную трассировку лучей (bidirectional path tracing). Но к сожалению нигде в сети я так и не смог найти подробного объяснения данного алгоритма простыми словами. Все что я понял, это то, что лучи генерируются как из камеры так и из источников освещения, а затем происходит проверка на возможность соединения точек пересечения этих путей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть получается, если точки пересечения синего луча из камеры и белого луча из источника могут быть беспрепятственно соединены (на пути соединения нету преград) значит можно считать что луч из камеры может пройти по точкам y1, y0 прямо к источнику.

Но возникает множество вопросов:

1. Если источник не точечный, а имеет какую-то форму, получается точка из которой запускается луч источника должна быть случайно выбрана на поверхности этого источника (примерно как на рис. 1)? Если брать только центр - тогда ведь не будет отличий от точечного источника?
2. Нужно ли на каждый путь из камеры строить путь из источника, или из источника путь должен/может быть только один, в то время как из камеры для одного пикселя строится сразу несколько путей (семплов)?
3. Количество отскоков/переотражений/преломлений должно быть одинаково для пути из камеры и источника? Или нет?

Но на этом вопросы не заканчиваются. Я многократно натыкался на упоминания о том, что метод двунаправленной трассировки позволяет хорошо (в сравнении с обычной трассировкой) моделировать каустику для преломляющих объектов. Я решил провести мысленный эксперимент, и совершенно не понял каким образом метод двунаправленной трассировки вообще как-либо может быть полезен для этого.

***Пример 1***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь получается что путь в итоге будет построен, но количество отскоков будет крайне большим, и ни о какой каустике речи не идет, несмотря на то что луч из камеры направлен почти в ту же точку где заканчивается путь луча из источника.

***Пример 2***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь и вовсе получается что путь построен не будет, поскольку между конечными точками путей есть преграда, хотя он вполне мог быть построен если бы точка x3 соединялась с точкой y1, но по условиям алгоритма (если я все верно понимаю) соединяются только последние точки путей.

**Вопрос:**

В чем польза от такого алгоритма, если в немалом кол-ве случаев пути либо не простраиваются либо оказываются излишне длинными? Может быть я что-то не правильно понимаю? Я натыкался на многие источники, где данный алгоритм как-то описывался, но в основном он описывался математически (с применением всяких магических терминов типа biased-unbiased, PDF, BSDF и прочих), а не.. алгоритмически. Я не то чтобы силен в математике и всяческих математических обозначениях и формулировках, хотелось бы просто понять ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ, как правильно реализовывать в коде, как соединяются эти пути, в какой последовательности и прочее. Это ведь можно объяснить простыми словами, псевдокодом? Буду крайне признателен если кто-то наконец прольет свет на всё это.

Comment: оставлю тут в качестве комментария http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Light_Transport_III_Bidirectional_Methods/Bidirectional_Path_Tracing.html  да на английском, но есть код и графика по которой можно разобраться - ничего равного на русском не попадалось, мне кажется я понимаю как это работает, но не достаточно чтобы оформить это как ответ.